# How to disable default keypress navigation of flipview in windows8 xaml

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing a windows 8 xaml application. I am using flipview control to display items and I want to disable default keypress navigation of flipview.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what doesn't work:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
}
```

After some more digging, I don't see a way to intercept it.

This also doesn't work:

```
private void FlipView_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as FlipView).Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);
}
```

I tried changing the template, but there's nothing there that helps.

I tried sub-classing it to a custom control, but there's nothing to override.

Without disabling the TOUCH features, I don't think this can be done.

Wow, never thought I would say that.

Comment: As far as I can see, nothing has changed in Windows 10 :(